# SQL Pivot Query assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a table

```
+----+-------+----------+-------+--------------+
| ID | REQID |  VENDOR  | QUOTE | DELIVERYDATE |
+----+-------+----------+-------+--------------+
|  1 | R1    | Vendor_1 |    99 | 2014-06-15   |
|  2 | R1    | Vendor_2 |    88 | 2014-07-15   |
|  3 | R1    | Vendor_3 |    77 | 2014-08-15   |
|  4 | R2    | Vendor_4 |    66 | 2014-09-15   |
+----+-------+----------+-------+--------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0de7)

I need the query to return three columns with the Vendor as the `Pivot` point. So my rows would look like so:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Vendor_1  | Vendor_2  | Vendor_3  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 99        | 88        | 77        |
| 2014-6-15 | 2014-7-15 | 2014-8-15 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The `cte` returns the correct records, I just don't know how to write the Pivot part or if it is even possible to return what I need.

Comment: What about `Vendor_4`?  Are your columns dynamic?  If so, you'll need to use `dynamic sql` to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of SQL Server you are using but you can get the final result by unpivoting your date and quote columns first, then pivot the data. The basic syntax will be similar to:

```
select Vendor_1, Vendor_2, Vendor_3
from
(
   select vendor, col, value,
     row_number() over(partition by vendor
                       order by vendor) seq
   from vendorquotes
   cross apply
   (
     values
      ('Quote', cast(quote as varchar(10))),
      ('DeliveryDate', convert(varchar(10), deliverydate, 120))
   ) c(col, value)
) d
pivot
( 
  max(value)
  for vendor in (Vendor_1, Vendor_2, Vendor_3)
) pi;
```

[See SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0de7/7/0)

The critical thing with this is you need to use a windowing function like row_number so you can return multiple rows for each of the vendors.

If you have an unknown number of Vendors, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to get this result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vendor) 
                    from VendorQuotes
                    group by Vendor
                    order by Vendor
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               select vendor, col, value,
                 row_number() over(partition by vendor
                                   order by vendor) seq
               from vendorquotes
               cross apply
               (
                 values
                  (''Quote'', cast(quote as varchar(10))),
                  (''DeliveryDate'', convert(varchar(10), deliverydate, 120))
               ) c(col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for Vendor in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0de7/23/0)

Finally, if you want to pass in the ReqID as a parameter, then you can alter the dynamic SQL to be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ReqID varchar(20),
    @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)


SET @ParmDefinition = '@ReqID varchar(20)'
SET @ReqID = 'R1'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vendor) 
                    from VendorQuotes
                    where Reqid = @ReqID
                    group by Vendor
                    order by Vendor
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
               select vendor, col, value,
                 row_number() over(partition by vendor
                                   order by vendor) seq
               from vendorquotes
               cross apply
               (
                 values
                  (''Quote'', cast(quote as varchar(10))),
                  (''DeliveryDate'', convert(varchar(10), deliverydate, 120))
               ) c(col, value)
               where ReqID = @ReqID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for Vendor in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query, @ParmDefinition, @ReqID = @ReqID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0de7/30/0)

Comment: I find it disturbing how much nicer CROSS APPLY is over [UNPIVOT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0de7/66)

Comment: @bluefeet, I edited the fiddle you made here " http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0de7/58 " that didn't have the ReqID parameter and used a cte passing the ReqId parameter to it as an alternate way of getting the same results. I need to use a cte because I oversimplified my example and will have a join or two with the VendorQuote table. I will still be able to use your solution (I hope).

Comment: @ConradFrix CROSS APPLY is much easier to use IMO.

Comment: @AlanFisher you should still be able to do this using a CTE, my suggestion would be to try it and if you run into issues, then post a new question

Comment: @bluefeet, I have one last question and I think I will be good to go. I altered the fiddle again " http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/669611" to include the joined table and was able to get the results I need. Is it possible to somehow get column names output with the data? I'm not sure how I will be able to add the fields to a report via a stored procedure that have no fields names.

Comment: @AlanFisher You can easily do that but including the `col` in the final select list -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0de7/67

Answer (score -1):

To be honest (if I understand your question right) I think you should think this over again. I would do this as follows:

```
Vendor_name     Value     Date
Vendor_1        99        2014-6-15
Vendor_2        88        2014-7-15
Vendor_3        77        2014-8-15
```

This way you have all related data in one row.

If you put relevant data in columns you will need to add more columns if more vendors are added and you need to be sure all your related data input is in the same order all the time.

Comment: It looks like this is exactly how the data is being stored (check out the provided fiddle).  OP wants to display it differently though.  With that said, I wouldn't downvote this as a suggestion.

Comment: Ooops. My bad. I only had a look at the table above. So what you need is your output to look like the table above? If so you could add each Vendor to a temp array and do the same with the Qoutes and Dates. Based on the keys you can display things in rows then.